# Drawing on CGContext with semi-tranparent color vs opaque color and setting alpha

Tags: core-graphics

This may be a simple question, but I couldn't figure it out from docs.

Is there differnece between those two approaches?

```
let context = makeContext()
let color = CGColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
context.setFillColor(color)
```

and

```
let context = makeContext()
let color = CGColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
context.setAlpha(0.5)
context.setFillColor(color)
```

As I understand, `setAlpha` sets alpha both for filling and stroking, but other than that, are those two equivalent? And if I set alpha to 0.5 and color with alpha 0.5 – will it draw with alpha 0.25?

I checked it in sample project and it appears to be yes, but may be there is some caveats that I don't know.

Thanks!